# Managing absolute path and full path

Tags: c#, java, algorithm, file, automation

I've created a small program wich can read a .txt file.

This file contains a link to another file in this format `new_file.txt`

The goal is to return the path of the new file, so basically I'm doing this :

```
String newFileName = getFileName();
int index = oldFilePath.lastIndexOf('\\');
String path = oldFilePath.substring(0, index + 1);
String newFilePath = path + newFileName;
return newFilePath;
```

For example :

The first file I opened is : `C:\a\b\c\oldFile.txt`

In this file I found `newFile.txt`

So the new path will be : `C:\a\b\c\newFile.txt`

Nice, but what If I find something like this :

`..\` or `.\.\` or `...`

Is there any way to automate this mess ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tagged this as java as well as c#

In java look at FileNameUtils http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html

The normalize method should help

Comment: the problem is not to removing double and single dot path steps, but to go back in the path and chose the right folder.

Comment: You can use the methods in java.io.File to get the File's name, getParentFile will get the parent directory. You should be able to use these with FileNameUtils to get your path shouldn't you?

Answer (score 5):

In C#/.Net you have the rather cool [Path class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bdzys9w.aspx).

You can use [Path.GetFullPath( string pathname )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx) to resolve paths e.g. with `\..\` etc in them.

Use `Path.GetDirectory()`, `Path.GetFileName()`, `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` & `Path.GetExtension()` to pull names apart and `Path.Combine()` to put them back together again.